# PHP command is opening another window every time

Tags: php, windows, cmd, xampp

I am using XAMPP in my computer.

I have added xampp/php in my path.

Now, when I run any PHP command, it opens another window for output every time.

[image: image here]

When I run "php -v" it opens another window and closes immediately.

Comment: Check xampp settings.

Comment: What output do you get if you run `where php`?

Comment: where php gives me this "C:\xampp\php\php.exe"

Comment: If you find `C:\xampp\php\php.exe` in Windows explorer, right click on it and select "Properties", do you have something enabled in the "Compatibility" tab?

Comment: nothing is enabled in Compatibility tab

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas (and really intrigued).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CASE 1 - PERMISSIONS:**

The first time I had this error, the problem was that my php folder only had read permissions, when I changed the permissions to: read and write php worked correctly.

**CASE 2 - VIRUS:**

The second time I had this error, it was because of two programs (virus) called: explorer.exe and svchost.exe. **In this case, the best solutions are: format the PC or try an antivirus** (the Windows defender does not detect them).

I fix the problem manually, if you also want to do it I detail the steps here:

**IMPORTANT:**

**1)** Check if your problem is the same: Open the "Task Manager" and look for these in the "Startup" and "Processes" tab.

- explorer.exe (Different from windows explorer)
- svchost.exe (It appears without name in the "processes" tab)

If this is not your case, the steps will not work, it is possible that another virus is causing the problem.

**2)** Make a backup, in case something goes wrong and you have to format your computer.

**GUIDE:**

**Step 1:** Open the "Task Manager", click on the "startup" tab, look for the names: explorer.exe and svchost.exe, mark them as disabled and restart the computer.

**Step 2:** In a file explorer, open the window: "Folder options", click on the "view" tab, enable the option: "Show hidden files and folders" and below disable the option: "Hide protected operating system files", then click the Apply button and close the window.

**Step 3:** Find these files and delete them, if the system does not let you delete them you will have to change the owner of the files:

If you have doubts about these files you can search them on the internet. These files should not be in that folder.

```
 C:\Windows\System\cmsys.cmn
 C:\Windows\System\explorer.exe
 C:\Windows\System\spoolv.exe
 C:\Windows\System\svchost.exe
 C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\mrsys.exe
```

**Step 4:** It is recommended to replace your PHP folder and reconfigure it *(In my case when executing PHP the virus was re-generated and I had to follow all the steps again).*

**Step 5:** Restart the computer, open the command prompt and try the "php -v" command. *Don't forget to enable "Hide protected operating system files" option in "Folder options".*

After these steps PHP worked correctly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting... But PHP doesn't really need to write anything there, as far as I know. This is a pretty good mystery :)

Comment: Thanks. Trojan causes that problem.
Some of my programs are infected by trojan. when i execute them trojan re-generates automatically, so i used process blocker to block that trojan. 

replaced php.exe with fresh file. Now its ok

Comment: Thanks, had the same problem on a virtual machine. I installed Trojan-Remover from simply super software, and installed php in a new folder, editing the system-path to the new folder and everything was fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem appears because you don't run your commands as Admin. So try to start the "cmd" as Administrator then the command should run in the same window. I had the same problem before some time.

After that i have used the Git bash to work with. And after some trouble i used the Windows 10 Linux subsystem.

Comment: "cmd" as Administrator , Git Bash as administrator both giving me same result. It is still opening a new window every time.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I've been running command-line PHP on Windows for over a decade (mostly using the official binaries, but also Xampp now and then) and never found this issue. What does PHP need administrator privileges for and how is Xampp binary different?