# CMD window pop up for a second and closes

Tags: laravel, windows, cmd

I'm trying to open a laravel project,i'm using xamp once I type `php artisan serve` on cmd another cmd window pops up for a second and close. The new cmd window has this url on top:

`appdata/local/temp/?582-490/php.exe`

Any solutions ?

Comment: what happens if you run cmd manually and write `php --version`?

Comment: @AliPadida same thing another cmd window pop up

Comment: I'm guessing you have a problem with php executable, Try reinstalling php in a different location and adding that location to PATH environment variables. Also remove the last one from PATH.

Comment: @AliPadida i'll try it , thanks for your reply

Comment: @AliPadida https://imgur.com/4YykP5l

Comment: Edit `Path` variable in System & User sections. Look for PHP directory. You can run cmd and type `where php` to see the directory and match inside `Path`

Comment: same problem ...

Comment: are you able to use other commands with cmd? like `ping 8.8.8.8` for example.

Comment: yes it works fine

Comment: what does `where php` output? and have you installed php standalone or using XAMP, WAMP or others? also please add these details and the steps you have done to the question for other viewers.

Comment: output of where php "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\php.exe" and i'm using xamp

Comment: actually they are both "wamp and xamp" installed on my computer , i don't know if it's a problem ?

Comment: yes that might cause a problem. It's better to have one of those. check this post as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542147/php-command-is-opening-another-window-every-time

Comment: don't use relative paths. When you doubleclick your batch file, the working folder is `C:\windows\system32`. Your relative path from there points to `C:\windowssystem32\appdata\local\temp\...`. Use an absolute path like `%userprofile%\appdata\local\temp\...` or `%temp%\...`. Note: the correct path separator in Windows is a backslash, not a slash. Note: no wildcards (`?`) allowed in a path except in the very last element.